# Adjoint action of special orthogonal groups on their Lie algebras

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, orthogonal-matrices, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $SO(n)$ be the Lie group of $n\times n$ special orthogonal matrices with real coefficients, then the set of the $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrices $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ is its Lie algebra. I know that the adjoint representation of $SO(n)$ induces an action of $SO(n)$ on $\mathfrak{so}(n)$
$$\alpha:SO(n)\times\mathfrak{so}(n)\longrightarrow\mathfrak{so}(n)$$
given by $\alpha(A,B)=ABA^{-1}$. Now let $n=4$. I know that, in this case, the Lie algebra of $SO(4)$ splits as
$$\mathfrak{so}(4)\cong\mathfrak{so}(3)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(3)$$
My question is: can I find some relations between the action of $SO(4)$ on $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ and the action of $SO(3)$ on the two different copies of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ that appear in the direct sum? I suppose that there could be a way to assign a matrix in $SO(3)$, which acts on $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, to a matrix in $SO(4)$, which acts on $\mathfrak{so}(4)$, but I don't know how I could do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a double cover map $\pi:SO(4)\rightarrow SO(3)\times SO(3)$, so every matrix in $SO(4)$ projects to a pair of matrices in $SO(3)$.  I'll write this as $\pi(A) =  (A_1,A_2)$.

Now, given $\pi$, I claim that you can choose an isomorphism $\psi:\mathfrak{so}(4)\cong \mathfrak{so}(3)\oplus \mathfrak{so}(3)$  (which I'll denote as $\psi(X) = (X_1, X_2)$) in such a way so that $\psi(AXA^{-1}) = (A_1 X_1 A_1^{-1}, A_2 X_2 A_2^{-1})$.

So, let's unravel this.  To begin with, I'm going to assume you're familiar with the double cover $\phi:SU(2)\rightarrow SO(3)$ and the double cover $\rho: SU(2)\times SU(2)\rightarrow SO(4)$.  The map $\phi$ has kernel $\{ \pm I_2\}$, while the map $\rho$ has kernel $\{\pm (I_2,I_2)\}$ (and I'm using the notation $I_n$ to denote the $n\times n$ identity matrix).

Where does $\pi$ come from?  Well, consider the composition $SU(2)\times SU(2)\xrightarrow{\rho} SO(4)\rightarrow SO(4)/\{\pm I_4\}$  Since $\rho^{-1}(I_4) = \{\pm (I_2, -I_2)$}, the kernel of the composition is $\{(\pm I_2, \pm I_n)\}$.  It follows that $SO(4)/\{\pm I_4\}\cong SO(3)\times SO(3)$.  Explicitly, the map $\pi:SO(4)\rightarrow SO(3)\times SO(3)$ is obtained as follows.  Given $A\in SO(4)$, pick $B\in \rho^{-1}(A)\subseteq SU(2)\times SU(2)$ and then apply $(\phi, \phi)$ to it.  Of course, given $A\in SO(4)$, there are *two* choices for $B\in \rho^{-1}(A)$, but $(\phi,\phi)$ has the same image

Now, where does $\psi$ come from?  Well, if we write $\pi_\ast$ for the differential $\mathfrak{so}(4)\rightarrow \mathfrak{so}(3)\oplus \mathfrak{so}(3)$, then we use $\psi = (\phi_\ast, \phi_\ast)\circ (\rho_\ast)^{-1}$.  Note that even though $\rho$ is not an isomorphism, $\rho_\ast$ is, so this makes sense.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you! I have just one question: since $(\phi,\phi)$ has the same image when applied to each of the two elements of $\rho^{-1}(A)$, can I write that $\pi=(\phi,\phi)\circ(\rho)^{-1}$ and $\pi_{\ast}=\psi$?

Comment: I don't like writing $(\phi,\phi)\circ (\rho)^{-1}$ because that notation, to me, signifies that $\rho$ has an inverse (as a function), which it does not.  For the other question, yes $\pi_\ast = \psi$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I tried to rewrite the details of your answer, but I don't fully understand why $\psi(AXA^{-1})=(A_1X_1A_1^{-1},A_2X_2A_2^{-1})$. Does it descend from the definition of $\rho$ and $\phi$?

Comment: @Lukath:  First, given a Lie group homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$, with induced map $f_\ast:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{h}$, that $f_\ast (Ad_g X) = Ad_{f(g)} f_\ast h$.  Now, using this, I'd compute $(\rho_\ast)^{-1}(AXA^{-1})$ as follows.  Writing $\rho^{-1}(A) = \pm (A', A'')$ and $(\rho_\ast)^{-1}(X) = (X', X'')$, we want to verify that $\rho_\ast (A' X' (A')^{-1}, A'' X'' (A'')^{-1}) = AXA^{-1}$  But applying the first sentence of this comment, $\rho_\ast(A' X' (A')^{-1}, A'' X'' (A'')^{-1}) = Ad_{\rho(\pm(A', A''))} \rho_\ast(X', X'') = Ad_{A} X = AXA^{-1}$.....

Comment: So this verifies that $(\rho_\ast)^{-1}(AXA^{-1}) = (A' X' (A')^{-1}, A'' X'' (A'')^{-1})$.  Now you just need to compute what $(\phi, \phi)$ does to this...

Comment: So basically, if I put $\phi(A')=A_1$ and $\phi(A'')=A_2$, I can compute $(\phi_\ast,\phi_\ast)(A'X'(A')^{-1},A''X''(A'')^{-1})=(Ad_{A_1}X_{1},Ad_{A_2}X_{2})$, where $X_1=\phi_{\ast}(X')$ and $X_2=\phi_{\ast}(X'')$, and I'm done. The property $f_{\ast}(Ad_g X)=Ad_{f(g)}f_{\ast}X$ holds for every Lie group homomorphism or for those who induce a Lie algebra isomorphism only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107188/discussion-between-lukath-and-jason-devito).

Comment: Every homomorphism:  if $\gamma = \exp(tX)$, then $f_\ast Ad_g X = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} f( C_g \gamma(t))$, where $C_g$ denotes conjugation by $g$.  Since $f$ is a homomorphism, $f(C_g\gamma(t)) = f(g \gamma(t) g^{-1} = f(g) (f\circ \gamma)(t) f(g)^{-1} = C_{f(g)} (f\circ \gamma)$.  So, by the chain rule, $f_\ast (Ad_g X)= (C_{f(g)})_\ast f_\ast X$, and $(C_{f(g)})_\ast = Ad_{f(g)}$ by definition of $Ad$.